# How to update label text from a timer event handler in a different class?

Tags: c#, string, forms, timer, label

I have a form with a label in it called `labelTime`.
In another class called `TimeCalculate` I have a `Timer` with `Timer_tick` event handler. 
In this class I also have a function `GetTime()` that returns the time in string format.
I want this string to appear in `labelTime` for every `Timer_tick`.
Is there a way to achieve that?

```
public void MyTimer(Label o_TimeLabel) 
{
  Timer Clock = new Timer(); 
  Clock.Tag = o_TimeLabel.Text; 
  Clock.Interval = 1000; Clock.Start(); 
  Clock.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick); 
} 

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs eArgs) 
{ 
  if (sender == Clock) 
  { 
    //LabelTime.Text = GetTime(); <-- I want this to work! 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Rebecca can you show what existing code you have so that we can see what's going on when the timer event gets Invoked..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Timer` and `Timer_Tick` event do not need to be in the same class as your `Label`, you can create a simple custom event to publish/subscribe to your `Timer_Tick` `event`.

Your `TimeCalculate` class:

```
namespace StackOverflow.WinForms
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public class TimeCalculate
    {
        private Timer timer;

        private string theTime;
        public string TheTime
        {
            get
            {
                return theTime;
            }
            set
            {
                theTime = value;
                OnTheTimeChanged(this.theTime);
            }
        }

        public TimeCalculate()
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TheTime = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }

        public delegate void TimerTickHandler(string newTime);
        public event TimerTickHandler TheTimeChanged;

        protected void OnTheTimeChanged(string newTime)
        {
            if (TheTimeChanged != null)
            {
                TheTimeChanged(newTime);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The extremely simplified example above shows how you can use a `delegate` and `event` to `publish` a notification when the `Timer_Tick` `Timer` object event fires.

Any objects that require notification when the `Timer_Tick` event fires (I.E. your time is updated) need only to `subscribe` to your custom event publisher:

```
namespace StackOverflow.WinForms
{
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TimeCalculate timeCalculate;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.timeCalculate = new TimeCalculate();
            this.timeCalculate.TheTimeChanged += new TimeCalculate.TimerTickHandler(TimeHasChanged);

        }

        protected void TimeHasChanged(string newTime)
        {
            this.txtTheTime.Text = newTime;
        }
    }
}
```

We create an instance of the `TimeCalcualte` class before subscribing to the `TimerTickHandler` event specifying a method (`TimeHasChanged`) to handle the notification.  Note that `txtTheTime` is the name I gave a `TextBox` on my form.

Comment: @ColinSteel - It is more code yes, however, there are reasons someone might prefer this solution, such as not mixing logics.

Additionally if this solution allows other objects that might want to utilise the `TimeCalcualte` class `Timer_Tick` event to do so without requiring their own `Timer` implementation.  They need only subscribe to the `TimerTickHandle` event.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Timer and its event in the same form as the Label

EDIT

Since you have done it that way, you need to;

Declare the Timer object as an instance variable, outside of the constructor, initialise it in the constructor.
Don't have to worry about testing 'sender == Clock'.
And have a Label instance object in this class as well, setting it to the Label you pass as a parameter in the constructor.

```
    Timer Clock;
    Label LabelTime;
    public void MyTimer(Label o_TimeLabel) 
    {
      LabelTime = o_TimeLabel;
      Clock = new Timer(); 
      Clock.Tag = o_TimeLabel.Text; 
      Clock.Interval = 1000;
      Clock.Start(); 
      Clock.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick); 
    } 

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs eArgs) 
    { 
      LabelTime.Text = GetTime(); // For your custom time
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. I guess that is the best option.

Comment: But I still recommend my first, using Visual Studio you can drag and drop a Timer onto your form, set the interval and text of the Timer in the GUI and then you only have to worry about the Tick event in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the second option but I can't send a Label as a parameter. It gives me the following error:
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property.

Answer (score 1):

Rebecca in your Time_Tick Event you could do the following

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
  lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: lblTime is in a different form so can't access it from where Timer_Tick is declared. 
Plus, I don't want  the current time - I'm calculating the time I'm inside the application. But that's another issue.

Comment: I posted that prior to me updating your code sample in your original question. also try to update your question to reflect the fact in the issue(s) you have stated in your comment